# caching UIViewControllers on the UIStoryBoard for better performance

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am building a todo app.

I am using the new storyboard option introduced in iOS 5.

i notice VC's are not being cached which creates a performance issue on my app.

one of my app's VC is titled "task details" and is widely use. i noticed viewDidLoad: is called every time the screen is displayed which takes about a second (being a rather complicated screen which is party constructed by code).

at first i used segues and connected other screens to this screen. whenever it was needed i'd use:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTaskDetails" sender:self];
```

i would prepare it's model with:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

then i noticed the performance issue. i investigated and saw viewDidLoad is loaded again and again. i was forced to stop working with segues and cache the TaskDetailsViewController and manually add it as a modal. I wonder if there is a solution for caching "popular" VCs on storyBoards. Otherwise, i will end up having a half-half solution which will work but les elegantly - and elegancy is important in our profession, isn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

UIStoryboard does not provide any caching mechanism. You'll have to cache view controllers on your own.

You could cache the data a particular view controller is based on so the load time is faster.